# How should I close a MySQL pool connection correctly within a NodeJS application?

Tags: mysql, node.js, connection, pool

I have a code like following:

```
import { RowDataPacket, FieldPacket } from "mysql2";
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express";

import { pool } from "../config/db";
import { IUser } from "../models/user";

class User {

  static async readAll(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    let user: IUser;
    let users: [IUser];
    await pool.execute<IUser[]>("SELECT * FROM users")
      .then((result) => {
        const [users] = result as [RowDataPacket, FieldPacket[]];
        res.send(users);
      })
      .catch(err => { console.log(err); next(); })
      // .finally(() => pool.end());
  }

  static async readById(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    await pool.execute<IUser & RowDataPacket[]>(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?",
      [req.params.id])
      .then(result => res.status(200).json(result))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  };


  static async create(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    await pool.execute<IUser & RowDataPacket[]>(
      "INSERT INTO users (email, password, username , admin) VALUES(?,?,?,?)",
      [req.body.email, req.body.password, req.body.username = req.body.email, req.body.admin])
      .then(() => {
        res.status(200).json(("user created successfully"));
      })
      .catch(err => { console.log(err); next(); })


  }

  static async update(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    await pool.execute<IUser & RowDataPacket[]>(
      "UPDATE users SET email = ?, password = ?, admin = ? WHERE id = ?",
      [req.body.email, req.body.password, req.body.username, req.body.admin, req.body.id])
      .then((result => res.status(201).json("updated user" + "SELECT LAST UPDATED ID()")))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }


  static async remove(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    await pool.execute<IUser & RowDataPacket[]>(
      "DELETE FROM users WHERE id = ?",
      [req.params.id]);

  }
}


export { User };
```

I am wondering to know how should I close the pool connection? I tried to add `.finally(() => pool.end());` at the end of the each function (as you can see one of them I have commented outin `readAll()` function) but it closes the pool and I get `the pool is close` error message for other requests.

So hw should I close a `pool` correctly?

EDIT: This is `/config/db` file:

```
import mysql from "mysql2";

const pool =  mysql.createPool(
  {
  host : (process.env.DB_HOST),
  user : (process.env.DB_USER),
  password:  (process.env.DB_PASSWORD ),
  database: (process.env.DB_NAME ),
  waitForConnections: true,
  connectionLimit: 10,
  queueLimit: 0
  }).promise();
```

Comment: You don't need to 'close to pool'. The point of the pool is that it manages connections to the database for the duration of your program. So just let it do its thing

Comment: @lpizzinidev: I added it in the `EDIT` section.

Comment: @Evert: So shouldn't I add anything about it's closing inside my code? like `SIGTERM => pool.end()`?

Comment: @best_of_man no everything will close itself. The only reason you might want to hook into these events is to delay exiting to give queries a chance to complete. TCP connections close themselves.